# Как создать коллекцию коллекций в VBA?

Tags: vba, коллекции

Суть такова, я разбиваю слово на массив слов по разделителю /, заполняю коллекцию partsWord этими значениями
Но у меня есть коллекция groups, которая должна хранить коллекции partsWords, и это никак не получается сделать...

```
    Dim variants As New Collection
    Dim groups As Collection
...
    Set groups = New Collection
    For Each word In words

        Set variants = New Collection

        partsWord = Split(word, "/")
        For Each part In partsWord
            variants.Add (part)
        Next

        groups.Add (variants) 'не получается

    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

В строке `groups.Add (variants)` уберите скобки, чтобы получилось `groups.Add variants`.
Так же, `part` и `word` должны быть объявлены как тип данных `Variant` или `Object`. Возможно это у Вас так и сделано, но в представленном коде этого не видно.